# A grep for Windows that works

Tags: windows, grep

I need to search a very large file (a Registry export file) for a specific string. Registry Editor has no way of simply viewing a Registry file and this file is too large to open in a text editor without impacting performance. So, for this I need something like `grep`. I have `grep` from GnuWin32 installed, but any time I try to use it, it returns a "memory exhausted" message. Is there a simple-to-install grep package for Windows that works?

Comment: Have you tried find? It has nothing common with the find of unix; it's actually the grep of windows.

Comment: I've had to write custom programs to do stuff like this in past. special buffering techniques are required for very large streams, and text streams aren't supposed to work that way. you have to encode the binary data back to text before you can search it, so its a non-trivial problem.

Comment: @GombaiSándor I think I have and it is inadequate.

Comment: There are programs that provide additional functionally which are registry editors O&O has one

Comment: is it feasible to just copy to a linux system?

Comment: No, findstr is the grep of Windows. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx

Comment: Indeed, this findstr looks more similar to grep than find. I wonder why the useful stuff is not packed with the os but the almost useful. (In the w2000/xp era, when I had to parse texts under win, I installed a native gawk from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm.)